# React with Typescript object destructure while setting state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a type

```
export type Team={TeamID:string,Description:string}
const [teamdropdownvalues,setTeamValue]=useState<Team[]>([])
const{team}=apiresult
```

in above result `team` I am getting array of `id,description,name,sortorder`. In setstate I am trying array destructure to get only `id and description` since my type Team I have only TeamID and Desciption
I tried like below I am getting error.

```
setTeamValue({
TeamID:team.teamID,
Description:team.Description
})
```

can somebody help how to destructure while setting state.I just started learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to transform the `team` variable into an array of objects, each having two keys: `TeamId` and `Description`. After that, you can update the state with the resulting array:

```
const teamValues = team.map(({ teamID, Description }) => ({
  TeamID: teamID,
  Description,
}));

setTeamValue(teamValues);
```

Comment: Thanks I am using typescript inside map function for ```teamID and Description``` i am getting error Binding element 'teamID' implicitly has an 'any' type

Comment: It's because we didn't define the type for `team`. It's possible to do directly in map like this: `team.map(({ teamID, Description }: { teamID: string, Description: string }) => ({ ... })`, or we can set the corresponding type for `apiresult`.

Comment: HI thanks again it works when i log ```teamValues``` i do see destructured object. after that I am setting state.```setTeamValues(teamValues)``` now when I log ```teamdropdownvalues``` I am getting empty array. I declare state as ```const [teamdropdownvalues,setTeamValue]=useState<Team[]>([])```

Comment: Thanks it works when i pass as props it have values .after setting state and log it shows empty but in my component I am able to bind.